# OpenGL: How to clear only a part of the screen?

Tags: c++, opengl

Is it possible to not clear entire screen when using glClear() function? I need to clear only a part of the screen to save some rendering time, otherwise i would have to redraw half of the screen every frame, even if nothing is happening on the other half.

Of course this should be done as quickly (or quickier) as the glClear() is now.

Comment: Just an idea: Could you set the viewport to half of the screen?

Comment: @chris_l: viewport does not affect Clear.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You might want to look into glScissor.  From the documentation:

> While scissor test is enabled, only pixels that lie within the scissor box can be modified by drawing commands.

Comment: and specifically, from the Clear documentation: [...], the scissor test, [...] affect the operation of glClear. +1.

Answer (score 5):

To clear only a specific rectangular region, enable `ScissorTest` and call `Clear`. Once enabled, only pixels within the scissor box will be affected by drawing commands, so disable `ScissorTest` when you need to modify the outside area again.

OpenTK example:

```
GL.Enable (EnableCap.ScissorTest);
GL.Scissor (ViewportX, ViewportY, ViewportWidth, ViewportHeight);
GL.Clear (ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);
GL.Disable (EnableCap.ScissorTest);
```

Answer (score 1):

Draw a giant quad :) Apply this to just half your screen.

http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/transformations.htm#tran0090

Comment: isnt drawing quad a bit too slow for this?

Comment: @Newbie Got measurements to show that a scissor clear is faster than a quad draw? I'd expect draw to be the main optimized path. I'd expect scissor clear to be a corner case far off in hypothetical land. I'm not saying draw is faster either, btw.