# OpenGL - Clear specific region of the screen only

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

`GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit)` wipes the screen with the clear colour.

How can I clear only a specific rectangular region?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026300/opengl-how-to-clear-only-a-part-of-the-screen

Answer (score 2):

With scissor test enabled, only pixels that lie within the scissor box can be modified by drawing commands.

```
GL.Enable (EnableCap.ScissorTest);
GL.Scissor (ViewportX, ViewportY, ViewportWidth, ViewportHeight);
GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
```